# How can I access another struct value

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct

I have a struct dictionary and I need to pull out an URL from it. So my question is how can I grab `Articles` struct value `rssUrl`to use it so after I can use that value for `SafariServices`?

```
struct Article {
    let rssUrl: String
    let text: String

    init(dict: [String : String]){
        text = dict["text"] ?? ""
        rssUrl = dict["rssUrl"] ?? ""

    }
}
```

grab the value and use it here

```
struct dataUrl {
    //grab rssUrl to use later as an Url

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend @Chris' answer:

You need at best pass the reference `Article` Which is fun because structs are Value types, not references.

```
struct Article {
    let rssUrl: String
    let text: String

    init(dict: [String : String]){
        text = dict["text"] ?? ""
        rssUrl = dict["rssUrl"] ?? ""

    }
}


    struct dataUrl {
       let someOtherURL: URL
        //grab rssUrl to use later as an Url

    }
```

In some context:

```
func doSmth() {
 let article = Article(dict: dictionary)

 // You need to unwrap this first
 if let someOtherURL = URL(string: article.rssUrl) {
   let dataURL = DataURL(someOtherURL)  
 } 
}
```

in other case you could make `Article` dependency in your `dataUrl` object like this and init it with article

```
  struct dataUrl {

       let article: Article

       /// Create get-only variable like this to return immediately.
       var someOtherURL: URL? {
         return URL(string: article.rssUrl) 
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to access a property from your Article struct you simply just need to use the standard dot notation -

```
let article = Article(dict: yourdictionaryobject)
article.rssUrl // returns your url
```